# Python script to take input yaml file to create a sns topic

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, yaml, devops, amazon-sns

This script is not giving any error, it is just displaying the yaml code on the console

Python Script:

test_sns_topic.py

```
import boto3
import yaml

client =  boto3.resource(
's3',
aws_access_key_id = '',
aws_secret_access_key = '',
aws_session_token = '',
region_name = 'us-west-2'

)

sns = boto3.client('sns')

with open('sns.yaml') as f:
   data = yaml.load(f,Loader= yaml.FullLoader)
   print(data)
```

sns.yaml

```
Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
Properties:
  DisplayName: Test
  KmsMasterKeyID: 7fba2279-673-73878748343
  TopicName: test_sns_topic
```

I am trying to create a topic using python script which takes yaml file as input.

Output:

It is now reading the yaml file but not creating any topic in the aws, it is just displaying the yaml code on the console.

Comment: That seems a cloudformation statement to create a sns topic. The boto3 client to create a sns topic is like `sns.create_topic(Name='my-topic')`

Comment: @AlexandreJuma thanks for taking a look into this, I made changes but it is still giving me an error.

Comment: What is the latest error that you get?

Comment: @balderman
<code>
import boto3
import yaml

client =  boto3.resource(
's3',
aws_access_key_id = '',
aws_secret_access_key = '',
aws_session_token = '',
region_name = 'us-west-2'

)

sns = boto3.client('sns')

with open('sns.yaml') as f:
   data = yaml.load(f,Loader= yaml.FullLoader)
   print(data)
<code>
but this script is just displaying the yaml data but not executing yaml instructions.

Comment: I have asked what is the latest error but you have posted code.

Comment: @balderman now I am not getting any error.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not - please describe it.

Comment: but this script is just displaying the yaml data but not executing yaml instructions or creating any topic.

Comment: it is just reading the yaml file and displaying the yaml instructions on the console, but is not creating any topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code looks like it belongs in a CloudFormation template:

```yaml
Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
Properties:
  DisplayName: Test
  KmsMasterKeyID: 7fba2279-673-73878748343
  TopicName: test_sns_topic
```

(It is a *part* of a template, not a complete template.)

AWS CloudFormation can deploy infrastructure based on definitions from a template. For this snippet, it would create an Amazon SNS topic with the given name and KMS key. It should be deployed as part of a more-complete CloudFormation template. As written, **it will not do anything from Python**.

If you wish to create an Amazon SNS topic from Python (instead of CloudFormation), then you should use the [`create_topic()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.create_topic) command.